# nginx pretty url's smf unknown directive

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with nginx to see if a user can help me, I can not activate pretty url in my forum smf

Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "action=$1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myweb.com:48
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

```
rewrite ^/profile/([^/]+)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=profile;user=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(activate|admin|announce|attachapprove|buddy|calendar|clock|collapse)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(coppa|credits|deletemsg|display|dlattach|editpoll|editpoll2|emailuser)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(findmember|groups|help|helpadmin|im|jseditor|jsmodify|jsoption)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(lock|lockvoting|login|login2|logout|markasread|mergetopics|mlist)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(moderate|modifycat|modifykarma|modifyrespetos|movetopic|movetopic2|notify|notifyboard)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(openidreturn|pm|post|post2|printpage|profile|quotefast|quickmod)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(quickmod2|recent|register|register2|reminder|removepoll|removetopic2|reporttm)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(requestmembers|restoretopic|search|search2|sendtopic|smstats|suggest|spellcheck)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(splittopics|stats|sticky|theme|topicsolved|trackip|about:mozilla|about:unknown)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(unread|unreadreplies|verificationcode|viewprofile|vote|viewquery|viewsmfile|who)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(.xml|shop|shop|xmlhttp)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;action=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 last;
rewrite ^/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 last;
rewrite ^/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.0 last;
rewrite ^/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*|msg[0-9]*|new)/?$ /./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.$3 last;
```

Comment: `;` is an end-of-line delimiter. You will need to use quotes around any sub-expression containing `;` and `{}` characters.

Comment: Hello! thank you very much I do not understand very well it means that I must remove; and put "" from the beginning of rewriting to final dl? line by line?

Comment: If you use `;` within the rewritten URI - it must be quoted. For example: `rewrite ^/profile/([^/]+)/?$ "/./index.php?pretty;action=profile;user=$1" last;`

Comment: Thnx Richard! I try now 